# Checking Rationality Using FindInstance

Tags: equation-solving, findinstance

I need to find example if $x,\sqrt{x^2+6},\sqrt{x^2+12}$ all can be rational at once or not. But the following command
`FindInstance[Element[Sqrt[x + 6], Rationals], {x}]`returns an errors saying

`The methods available to FindInstance are insufficient to find the requested instances or prove they do not exist.`

Anyway to bypass this or modify the input to get result?

Edit `FindInstance[Element[y - 8.4, Rationals], {y}]` also returns the same error. Is this a bug or what?

Comment: Please, elaborate what means **"all can be rational at once or not"**

Comment: @JoséAntonioDíazNavas for example both √y and √(y+9) are rational for y =16. I need to x such that all three of those terms are rational

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe this?:

```
FindInstance[6 + x^2 == y^2 && 12 + x^2 == z^2, {x, y, z}, Rationals]
```

> {{x -> -(1/2), y -> -(5/2), z -> 7/2}}

Given that by definition $|c|=\sqrt{c^2}$ for $c\in\mathbb{R}$, then the solutions should be:

> {{x -> -(1/2), y -> 5/2, z -> 7/2}} || {{x -> 1/2, y -> 5/2, z -> 7/2}}

Answer (score 0):

You might try brute-force search, enumerating all (positive) rationals starting from 0:

`x = 0;
While[! (Element[Sqrt[x^2 + 6], Rationals] &&Element[Sqrt[x^2 + 12], Rationals]), 
 x = 1/(Floor[x] + 1 - FractionalPart[x])];
x`

with simple answer:
(* x = 1/2 *).

Comment: relying on a bit of luck that the answer occurs early in the sequence. This could take approximately forever.

Comment: Above one-liner check 10^6 distinct rationals/second. You can easily get 10^8/sec rewriting in C.

Comment: Ah, but the space of "all" rationals is infinite.  It is a fair point that such a puzzle likely has a "nice" answer though.

Comment: Space of all rationals representable in computer is finite, e.g. limited by memory. `FindInstance` probably uses algorithm like this for `Integers`, so why not for `Rationals`?

Answer (score 0):

A systematic look-up for `x^2 == y && 9 + y == z^2`

```
sol = Union[{x1/x2, x1^2/x2^2, z1/z2} /. 
       Solve[(9 + (x1/x2)^2 == (z1/z2)^2 && 0 <= x1 <= a && 0 < x2 <= a &&
    0 <= z1 <= a && 0 < z2 <= a) /. a -> 100, {x1, x2, z1, z2}, 
    Integers, Method -> Reduce]]

(*   {{0, 0, 3}, {13/28, 169/784, 85/28}, {11/20, 121/400, 61/20},
{16/21, 256/441, 65/21}, {7/8, 49/64, 25/8}, {5/4, 25/16, 13/4},
{8/5, 64/25, 17/5}, {28/15, 784/225, 53/15}, {9/4, 81/16, 15/4},
{65/24, 4225/576, 97/24}, {20/7, 400/49, 29/7}, {63/20, 3969/400, 87/20},
{55/16, 3025/256, 73/16}, {4, 16, 5}, {56/11, 3136/121, 65/11},
{45/8, 2025/64, 51/8}, {80/13, 6400/169, 89/13}, {77/12, 5929/144, 85/12},
{36/5, 1296/25, 39/5}, {35/4, 1225/16, 37/4}, {72/7, 5184/49, 75/7},
{40/3, 1600/9, 41/3}}   *)
```

and for `6 + x^2 == y^2 && 12 + x^2 == z^2`

```
sol2 = Union[{x1/x2, y1/y2, z1/z2} /. 
   Solve[(6 + (x1/x2)^2 == (y1/y2)^2 && 12 + (x1/x2)^2 == (z1/z2)^2 &&
    0 <= x1 <= a && 0 < x2 <= a && 0 <= y1 <= a && 0 < y2 <= a && 
   0 <= z1 <= a && 0 < z2 <= a) /. a -> 100, {x1, x2, y1, y2, z1, 
   z2}, Integers, Method -> Reduce]]

(*   {{1/2, 5/2, 7/2}}   *)
```

Seems to the the only solution.